# How to resolve "Package (...) Cannot be resolved" in Apache Karaf

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am new to Apache Karaf, I migrated from Felix.

I try to run a CDI test but can not resolve the red missing dependencies:

[image]

I am pretty sure I must download those red "packages" as `bundles` from mvnrepository but instead of `bundles` I only find `jar` to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bundle is a jar with some additional data in the MANIFEST.MF.

For example, if you look at that jar : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.2, you'll notice in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF those lines :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Built-By: jharting
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Implementation-Title: CDI APIs
Implementation-URL: http://cdi-spec.org
Implementation-Vendor: JBoss by Red Hat, Inc.
Implementation-Version: 20140411-1123
Specification-Title: CDI APIs
Specification-Vendor: JBoss by Red Hat, Inc.
Specification-Version: 1.2.0
Export-Package: javax.decorator;uses:="javax.enterprise.inject";versio
 n="1.1",javax.enterprise.context;uses:="javax.inject";version="1.1",j
 avax.enterprise.inject.spi;uses:="javax.enterprise.context.spi,javax.
 el,javax.enterprise.inject,javax.interceptor,javax.enterprise.event";
 version="1.1",javax.enterprise.util;version="1.1",javax.enterprise.ev
 ent;uses:="javax.enterprise.util";version="1.1",javax.enterprise.inje
 ct;uses:="javax.inject,javax.enterprise.util,javax.enterprise.context
 ";version="1.1",javax.enterprise.context.spi;version="1.1"
Tool: Bnd-0.0.357
Bundle-Name: CDI APIs
Bundle-Vendor: JBoss by Red Hat, Inc.
Bundle-Version: 1.2.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1397208243348
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Description: APIs for CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection fo
 r Java EE)
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
Import-Package: javax.decorator;version="1.1",javax.el;version="2.2",j
 avax.enterprise.context;version="1.1",javax.enterprise.context.spi;ve
 rsion="1.1",javax.enterprise.event;version="1.1",javax.enterprise.inj
 ect;version="1.1",javax.enterprise.inject.spi;version="1.1",javax.ent
 erprise.util;version="1.1",javax.inject,javax.interceptor;version="1.2"
Bundle-SymbolicName: javax.enterprise.cdi-api
Bundle-DocURL: http://jboss.org

Name: Build-Information
Maven-Version: 3.1.0
Build-Time: 20140411-1123
Os-Name: Linux
Java-Version: 1.7.0_45
Java-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Os-Version: 3.7.3-101.fc17.x86_64
Os-Arch: amd64
SCM: 5a0981caa28053c49f9e1932ba1f629a51e355c2
```

Bundle-* are the ones that interest you. For example, `Export-Package` contains `javax.enterprise.context;uses:=...;version="1.1"` which indicates that this bundle will export the package `javax.enterprise.context`.

So installing that bundle, will automatically provide to your other bundles the ability to `Import-Package` that package.

Note that if there wasn't any `Export-Package`, I know karaf can try to "wrap" your jar into a bundle. However, it can leads to non really optimal bundles. When you want a particular package but the official one is not osgi-friendly, you can check the servicemix organization, if any has been created specifically : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.

In your specific case, a `bundle install -s mvn:javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.2` (or dropping the jar in the deploy folder) should do the trick.

I highly encourage you to read the three OSGI layers (modularity, lifecycle & services) to better understand what karaf is doing behind the scene. For example this book, but you can surely find good informations on the internet too : https://www.manning.com/books/osgi-in-action

Comment: `bundle install -s mvn:` wont work cause its a offline-system, what I might be able todo is to download the maven-bundle on a stick, walk to the offline-system, install to the local .m2/repo and the call the command.

Comment: Note that you can configure your `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` to check the mvn links to your local repo if it can helps. However, if you are working exclusively offline, you can also just drop your jars in the deploy folder.

Comment: Yes, exclusievly offline. I drop all I need into deploy folder all the time, right as you suggested. :)

Comment: Hey if I folow your first link to mvnrepsitiory (`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.2`) you have a information-table there. The 6th row is called **Files** and contains **pom** and **jar**. In contrast to this files the url `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-api/1.1.3` does contain **bundle** instead. Why is your bundle not marked as **bundle** in mvnrepository?

Comment: I know that people that work with OSGi environment has tendency to use <packaging>bundle</packaging> in their pom.xml (which can be set only if you use the bundle plugin) which is maybe how mvnrepository check it. However, it's just a "nice to have", the real information is based on the MANIFEST.MD, I personally only check it